# elemmatch same field twice on array in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to filter against the same field in an array?. For example, I want to look for cars that have a main color as black, but not purple. (i.e. I want car1 to be returned, based on the example below)

I've tried using expressions like these below but they either return nothing or everything. I've tried using $and as well but it doesn't seem to be the right tool.

> > "info.colors" : { "$elemMatch" : { "main" : { "$in" : [ "black"]}}, "$elemMatch" : { "main" : { "$nin" : [ "purple"]}}}

and

> > "info.colors" : { "$elemMatch" : { "main" : { "$in" : [ "black"], "$nin": ["purple"]}}}

```
[{
"car": "car1",
"info": {
    "colors": [{
        "main": "green",
        "secondary": "blue"
    }, {
        "main": "black",
        "secondary": "red"
    }, {
        "main": "yellow",
        "secondary": "yellow"
    }],
    "price": "123"
},
"owner": "tom"
},
{
"car": "car2",
"info": {
    "colors": [{
        "main": "white",
        "secondary": "red"
    }, {
        "main": "black",
        "secondary": "red"
    }, {
        "main": "purple",
        "secondary": "grey"
    }],
    "price": "123"
},
"owner": "dick"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$elemMatch` for single criteria. `$eq` followed by `$ne` will work for you.

You can reach embedded array using dot notation with implicit and.

```
db.collection.find({"info.colors.main" : {$eq:"black", $ne: "purple"}})
```

Implicit and on same field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and

More information on querying embedded docs.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately, this query seems to be returning results that match each expression then combining them. For example, in my results, I would be getting a car that doesn't have main color black nor main color purple. But I only want cars that have main color black AND not main color purple.

Comment: You are welcome. Updated answer. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: That seems to have done it awesome, thanks for the help. Out of curiosity, if say i wanted to filter on more than one color for my expressions (say cars with colors black OR white AND not colors purple OR green) I would this still be possible?

Comment: yeah sure. You can use any combination. Something like `db.collection.find({"info.colors.main" : {$in:["black","white"], $nin: ["purple", "green"]}})
`